# Parse RSS publishedDate

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to parse the publishedDate from an RSS Feed, but no success...

i can show the dates using this code: `thefeeds[i].publishedDate`.. and the result is: `Sat, 02 Feb 2013 22:00:00 -0800` But, i want this more friendly...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var feedcontainer=document.getElementById("feeddiv")
        var feedurl="http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/folha/classificados/empregos/rss091.xml"
        var feedlimit=4
        var rssoutput="<ul>"
        function rssfeedsetup(){
            var feedpointer=new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl) //Google Feed API method
            feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit) //Google Feed API method
            feedpointer.load(displayfeed) //Google Feed API method
        }

        function displayfeed(result){
            if (!result.error){
                var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
                for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++){

<!-- I THINK I'M DOING THIS LINES WRONG!! -->
                var pubDate = thefeeds[i].publishedDate
                var date = new Date(pubDate);
                var months = Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
                var string = date.getDate() + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear()

<!-- END -->

                rssoutput+="<li><span>•</span> " + string + " - <a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "' target='_blank'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></li>"
                rssoutput+="</ul>"
                feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
            }
            else
            alert("Erro ao carregar as notícias!")
        }

        window.onload=function(){
            rssfeedsetup()
        }
        </script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What in your code goes wrong where exactly? What happens?

Comment: i can't show the date from rss itens

Comment: This is still very hazy. What result at which point isn't giving you the result you need? Are you getting any errors in the error console?

Comment: here `rssoutput+="<li><span>•</span> " + string + " - <a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "' target='_blank'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></li>"` where is "string" i want to show the date of publish item ... if i use this: `thefeeds[i].publishedDate` i got this, but i want this more friendly to reed...

Comment: wow.. looking close i found my error!.. o forget the branches `{ ` and `}` on `for` loop!

Comment: With the code as is, what is the output, for one row? **<li><span>•</span> undefined ...** or **<li><span>•</span> Sat, 02 Feb ...** or ...

Comment: Hey man i wrote that as an answer some minutes ago... :-S

Comment: yeah... sorry.. you were right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that a parentesis is missing(in the for-Loop), but i am not sure if it is only a copy paste error.
Like this th code will loop set **i** to a number which is not in the array ...

```
 ...
 for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++)
 //--> here  is missing {
 ...
 //--> at the end of the block }
 ...
```